# Protocol for Lightweight Authentication of Identity (PLAID) for Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption

I am looking for porting Protocol for Lightweight Authentication of Identity (PLAID) - http://www.humanservices.gov.au/corporate/publications-and-resources/plaid/ to Objective-C. Is there any source available to start for porting to Objective-C or C or C++ Programming language? I find only Java program available for PLAID.

Answer (score -1):

If you add these two pods to your Xcode workspace you shouldd be able to work with Plaid. I just started working with it and I think both of the pods are under development. I have been able to get the point of signing in with my bank account and there is an access token but I don't know how much farther I can go than that

```
pod 'plaid-ios-sdk'
pod 'plaid-ios-link'
```

Links:

https://github.com/simonlevy5/plaid-ios-link

https://github.com/simonlevy5/plaid-ios-sdk